# Unable to satisfy the following requirements

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a project with `Podfile` in it:

And in the `Podfile`:I have some three part `lib`:
Two of them:

```
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0.0-beta2'  #before is '~>3.8.1'
pod 'SDCycleScrollView'
```

Because I want to update the `SDWebImage` version from `~>3.8.1` to `~> 4.0.0-beta2`, but the `SDCycleScrollView` is base on `SDWebImage v3.7`, now there comes the error in `terminal`, how to resolve it?

The error:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `SDWebImage (~> 4.0.0-beta2)` required by `Podfile`
- `SDWebImage (~> 3.7)` required by `SDCycleScrollView (1.64)`
```

Comment: If SDCycleScrollView doesn't have a version that depends SDWebImage v4, then you won't be able to make this update and still use SDCycleScrollView.

Comment: could me let sdcyclescrollview use the 3.8.1v and update to 4.0.0_beta2 in someway? if the sdcycle do not update . then i will wait? or could me to fork the sdcyclescrollview ? and does this work?